# group by linq with combine columns

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have Object with the data like this below

[image]

I am looking for results like this

[image]

For this i am trying with the linq query below

```
 var results = (from l in res 
            group new
            {
                l.MDMChannelCallLetters,
                l.UserName,
                l.IsActive,
                l.IsLocal,
                l.IsNetwork,
                l.IsPrivate,                 
                l.RatecardDescription,
                l.RatecardName,
            } by l.RatecardId into g select new
            {
                // I am not sure what i need to do 

            } )
```

Could any one please help on this how to combine only particular column values with comma seperated) having  same ID using linq Query

Many thanks in advance !!!

Comment: I think you are confused about that `by l.RatecardId into g select new` line, separate that into `by l.RatecardId into g` and then `select new` on the following line and you'll realize that `select new` is LINQ's common select expression. Now, if you don't know how to code that select expression, you'll do well by reading a LINQ tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first group it by the common properties:

```
 var grouped = res.GroupBy(c => new {
      c.RatecardId,
      c.RatecardName,
      c.RatecardDescription,
      IsActive,
      IsPrivate,
      IsLocal,
      IsNetwork
 });
```

And then you need to select your final result.
Something like this:

```
var results = grouped.Select(c => new {
     c.Key.RatecardId,
     c.Key.RatecardName,
     c.Key.RatecardDescription,
     c.Key.IsActive,
     c.Key.IsPrivate,
     c.Key.IsLocal,
     c.Key.IsNetwork,
     MDMChannelCallLetters = string.Join(", ", c.Select(x => x.MDMChannelCallLetters)),
     UserName = string.Join(", ", c.Select(x => x.UserName))
});
```

Comment: If you group by MDMChannelCallLetters you cant get all elements individually to assign in a same property with the comma (,) separator.

Comment: Why `c.FirstOrDefault` instead of just `c.Key`?

Comment: Is the same thing. You can use Key or FirstOrDefault, never First() becouse it produce a NPE

Comment: No you definitely can use `First` here because there has to be at least one item for it to create a group in the first place.  Also  you don't need the `ToList` because `string.Join` will take a `IEnumerable`.

Comment: And the `Key` will never be `null` so you don't need the null conditional.

Answer (score 0):

So `Res` is the sequence that contains the rows from your first table. I haven't got a clue what `Res` are, so let's define that one element is a `Re`.

If you have a sequence of items, and you want to group them into groups of items that have something in common, you use [Enumerable.GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__). If you sequence is in a database and you use entity framework for this, you should use `Queryable.GroupBy`. The syntax is similar

GroupBy has a parameter `KeySelector`, which defines what properties that the groups should have in common. It also has a result selector: this selects what every group should contain.

```
var groupedItems = res.GroupBy(re => re => new

// KeySelector: what should the elements of a group have in common
// = make groups of Res with same RateCardId, RateCardName, ..., MdmChannelCallLetters
{
     Id = re.RateCardId,
     Name = re.RateCardName,
     Description = re.RateCardDescription,
     ...
     MdmChannel = re.MdmChannelCallLetters,
},

// ResultSelector: take the Key (= what do they have in common,
// and all Res that have these values for key
// to make one new object:
(key, resWithThisKey) => new
{
    RateCardId = key.Id,
    RateCardName = key.Name,
    ...
    MdmChannelCallLetters = key.MdmChannel,

    // You want to concatenate the user names:
    UserNames = String.Join(',', resWithThisKey.Select(re => re.UserName)),
});
```

There is an overload of GroupBy with a parameter `ElementSelector` where you can define the elements that should be in your group. This simplifies your ResultSelector:

```
var result = res.GroupBy( // KeySelector: see above

   // ElementSelector: what should the elements of each group be?
   // in your case: you want a group of UserNames
   re => re.UserName,

   // ResultSelector, similar as above, but now the elements of a group are the userNames
   (key, userNames) => new
   {
        RateCardId = key.Id,
        ...

        UserNames = String.Join('c', userNames),
   });
```